# How to make exe of autohotkey scripts?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

see example http://antun.vkrgnf.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/jttss02_insertmodule.png

download this application then see what i want http://antun.vkrgnf.com/?page_id=2

for example if i have a text like this

> Before you make that important call
>   (or after a configuration change) be
>   sure to check your connection and
>   volume with Skypes Test Call (echo
>   123) It takes less than a minute to
>   complete.

and if i select whole text via mouse or keyboard then something bar like this example tool which should have a button for different HTML tag to make content to html in any browser or software.

want to custom Text bar like this.

[image]

but independent like this

[alt text http://antun.vkrgnf.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/jttss01_mainwindow.png](http://antun.vkrgnf.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/jttss01_mainwindow.png)

Comment: Heh, it looks like the question title, the question, and the answer are talking about 3 different things entirely. Still, glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here http://lifehacker.com/167455/hack-attack-blogging-mark+up-made-easy